# rClone to mount Onedrive Business

Tags: onedrive, drive, rclone

Whenever I try to mount my onedrive on my pc, I face an issue. Right now my Org has more than 1 onedrive. (business plan 2)
and whenever I try to connect my onedrive, I get connected to other onedrive.

So when I fill the client id, secret code created by me. it shows other user drive. what is the issue?

I tried doing alot but always failed. In rClone it shows only 1 onedrive and that is other user onedrive.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by another OneDrive?  Another user's OneDrive?  A OneDrive with the same account but different contents?  Are you presented with different directories to choose from once you are authenticated?  If you're an admin in your org, or they haven't disabled the functionality for users to do so, go to https://aad.portal.azure.com , click on Users on the left, search for your account and click on it (don't check it) and then click on Sign-in logs on the left hand side.  Just to verify that your sign-in is actually being tracked in the tenant and you are connecting to what you think you are connecting to.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."